# Why am I getting an error as I try to call paintComponent?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, custom-component, paintcomponent

My class named `UI` extends `RoundButton` which is as follows :

```
public class RoundButton extends JButton {

    public RoundButton(String label) {
        super(label);
        this.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        Dimension size = this.getPreferredSize();
        size.height = size.width = Math.max(size.height, size.width);
        this.setPreferredSize(size);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        if(!GameState.getIfComplete()) { // If the game is not complete or has just started
            this.setBorder(null);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getSize().width, this.getSize().height);
            if(this.getModel().isArmed()) {
               g.setColor(Color.RED);
            }else {
                g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            }
            g.fillOval(0,0,this.getSize().width-1,this.getSize().height-1);
            super.paintComponent(g);
        }else {
            this.setBorder(null);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getSize().width, this.getSize().height);
            if(this.getModel().isArmed()) {
               g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            }else {
                g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            }
            g.fillOval(0,0,this.getSize().width-1,this.getSize().height-1);
            super.paintComponent(g); 
        }
    }
}
```

Inside `UI` there is a method named `disableAllButtons` which is as follows :

```
public void disableAllButtons() {
    int count =0 ;
    while(count <= buttons.length-1) {
        buttons[count].setEnabled(false);
        buttons[count].paintComponent(Graphics g); // GENERATES AN ERROR
        // where buttons[count] = new RoundButton()
        count++;  
    }
}
```

From this method I try to call,`paintComponent` I overrode in `RoundButton` class. But I get an error :

```
')' expected
';' expected
 not a statement
 cannot find symbol
 symbol: variable Graphics
 location: class UI
```

when I import `java.awt.Graphics` class.

Why is that ?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the call `buttons[count].paintComponent(Graphics g)`...

First of all, you should NEVER call `paintComponent` yourself, you should let the `RepaintManager` deal with it.  Use `repaint` instead.

Secondly, `Graphics g` is not a valid parameter, it's a deceleration.

Check out

- [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)
- [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)

For details about Swing and painting.

Also...calling `this.setBorder(null);` within you paint method is a really, really bad idea.  This will trigger a new repaint request to be posted on the Event Dispatching Thread over and over and over and over ... you get the idea.  It will consume you CPU